# Create JSONObject with gson and pass to constructor

Tags: java, json, gson

I would like to use the gson library to create a JSONObject from a file and pass that object to a constructor.

Let's say my json file named 'config.json' looks like this:

```
{"name": "my name"}
```

Then I would want to do something like this

```
File jsonFile = new File("config.json");
Gson jsonObject = gson.createJson(jsonFile);

OtherClass newInstance = new OtherClass(jsonObject);
```

And in OtherClass I could call

```
jsonObject.name;
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should consult the [Gson API](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Class%29), it's pretty comprehensive. You will want to utilize a FileReader to read your input file, and you need to pass in the class you are deserializing into as well:

```
OtherClass obj = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader(file), OtherClass.class);
```